# Maven template plugin?

Tags: java, maven

I've looked and I can't seem to find a standalone maven plugin that one could use to generate files with Maven.

I've seen a couple of projects that look like they *might* be going to do something like this, and I know the web start plugin uses velocity templates to generate the jnlp file. But I have not found anything that does this.

In case you're wondering why one would want this - I'd like to be able to generate Eclipse plugin.xml files as part of a PDE build.

Does anyone know of a Maven template plugin or how to generate Eclipse plugin.xml files from Maven?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was going to create this, but someone else beat me to it but: the [maven velocity plugin](http://code.google.com/p/velocity-maven-plugin/) can generate files based on templates (using velocity of course).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are looking for the [Maven Eclipse plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/) or the [Archetype plugin](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/).

Update:

Sorry didn't pay attention to the "PDE" ... perhaps [this codehaus pde-maven-plugin plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/pde-maven-plugin/) does what you need?

Comment: I don't think the Eclipse plugin generates plugin.xml files (for PDE builds) - I've looked more than once. Also, I don't know how I could use the archetype plugin for this? Can you provide examples?

Answer (score 0):

For a similar use case, I've developed this Maven plugin which allows to do powerful and easy templating/filtering using Groovy's GStrings. I find it much easier to use this for a Java developer than velocity and other "templating" languages.

https://github.com/gstring-maven-plugin/gstring-maven-plugin